# Where should I put this code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Here's the code, written to be written in a controller:

```
CategoryRepository categoryRepo = new CategoryRepository();
var categories = categoryRepo.FindAllCategories();
ViewBag.Categories = categories;
```

Now I'd like to use this to create a nice list of Categories dynamically.

```
<div id="leftnavigationbar">                
    <ul>
        @foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
        {
            //Create li here.    
        }

        <!-- ActionLink goes: Text, ActionName, Controller -->
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Libros", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Peliculas, Musica & Juegos", "Index", "Anuncios")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Computadoras", "Index", "Usuarios")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bienes Raices", "Index", "Ayuda")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Bolsa de Trabajo", "Index", "Contacto")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Deportes y Fitness", "Index", "Contacto")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Electronicos y Celulares", "Index", "Contacto")</li>
    </ul>            
</div>
```

Right now I'm writing this code to the _Layout.cshtml file. But I'd like to know where to write this so it runs always, sort of like a MasterPage.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

It appears that my initial intent isn't possible.

```
@foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(category.Name, "Index", "Home")</li>
}
```

Any suggestions on how accomplish what I'm trying to do? Just pull a list of categories and render them using a foreach loop. Then have it placed somewhere so it's viewable on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

As always you start by creating a view model:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller you fill the view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var categories = categoryRepo.FindAllCategories();
    var model = MapModelToViewModel(categories);
    return View(model);
}
```

And finally your strongly typed view could use a display template. Obviously the view will be strongly typed to IEnumerable

```
<ul>
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <!-- ActionLink goes: Text, ActionName, Controller -->
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Libros", "Index", "Home")</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And your display template (~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/CategoryViewModel.cshtml):

```
@model YourApp.Models.CategoryViewModel
<li>@Model.CategoryName</li>
```

As you can see with strongly typed views and display templates you don't even need to write loops in your views.

As an alternative to display templates you could use `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` helers. Phil Haack wrote a [nice blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) about them. I suspect that you were forced to use the ugly untyped ViewBag because this code is situated in your master template and you don't have a view model. No problem, with `Html.Action` you could have a specific controller that will do this:

```
public class CategoriesController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var categories = categoryRepo.FindAllCategories();
        var model = MapModelToViewModel(categories);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And then have a corresponding partial view which will take care of rendering the categories (`~/Views/Categories/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<YourApp.Models.CategoryViewModel>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

And finally use the same display template.

Now in your master page you could simply include this child action:

```
<ul>
    @Html.Action("index", "categories")

    <!-- ActionLink goes: Text, ActionName, Controller -->
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Libros", "Index", "Home")</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something called a 'partial view'.